# 3dsmax IIGameNode cannot get the correct world matrix matrix

Tags: 3d, game-development, gltf, 3dsmax

I tried to export node data to gltf using IIGameNode and everything worked fine except one model.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQoRI.png)，
These two models are instance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MjjR.png)

```
IIGameScene GameScene = Loader.Global.IGameInterface;
IIGameNode MAX_Node = GameScene.GetTopLevelNode(i);
var Matrix0 =MAX_Node.GetObjectTM(0).ToArray();
.........
```

When I check it in blender it looked like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJHYm.png)

I wonder if I'm missing some matrix?